# How to properly profile a c++ program using llvm, when program only exits on ctrl+c (sigint)?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, profiling, code-coverage

I'm trying to profile a c++ program using llvm, compiled with clang using the appropriate flags `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping`.

However, the program has no "natural" life end, and only exits using signals. On exit, the default.profraw is empty. I've tried using a signal handler and the following code executing when catching a signint:

```
                void (*_mcleanup)(void);
                _mcleanup = (void (*)(void))dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "_mcleanup");
                if (_mcleanup == NULL)
                {
                    cout <<  "Unable to find gprof exit hook";
                }

                else _mcleanup();
```

... which I haphazardly found in another thread. This generates a profraw file that actually contains data, however, seems to corrupt the default.profraw file to the point where it can't be uncompressed, generating an error when using:

```
llvm-profdata merge default.profraw -o default.profdata
```

The error message pretty much says zlib just can't uncompress the profraw file.

Does anyone else have experience trying to profile a c++ program that only exits using signals?

Answer (score 0):

By default, llvm [dumps profiling data on program exit](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/compiler-rt/lib/profile/InstrProfilingFile.c#L1219) using [`atexit()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html), so it should be sufficient to exit upon receiving the signal.

```c
signal(SIGINT, exit);
```

If your program runs under a supervisor which sends a different signal, you could add more handlers, or use a wrapper script like this.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

my-program &
pid=$!
trap "kill -SIGINT ${pid}" SIGTERM
wait
```

---

Alternately, llvm has a [continuous mode](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html#running-the-instrumented-program) which is supposedly able to dump complete coverage data even when killed by a signal or crash.  It can be enabled by compiling with flags

`-fprofile-generate -mllvm -runtime-counter-relocation`

and adding the `%c` specifier at runtime like

```bash
export LLVM_PROFILE_FILE='profile-%m%c.profdata'
my-program
```

However, this did not work for me as llvm-profdata complained about "truncated profile data".  And indeed the documentation warns

> Continuous mode does not support value profiling for PGO, and is only supported on Darwin at the moment. Support for Linux may be mostly complete but requires testing...